# How to backup all files in ansible playbook templates, without repetition of parameters

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a fairly basic ansible playbook, with tons of template tasks, copying to various paths. It looks like this

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ env }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Copy apple
      template:
        src: src/apple
        dest: "/usr/bin/apple"
        backup: true
    - name: Copy banana
      template:
        src: src/banana
        dest: "/usr/local/banana"
        backup: true
    - name: Copy coconut
      template:
        src: src/coconut
        dest: "/etc/apache2/coconut"
        backup: true
# Tons of similar template tasks
    - name: Copy zuccini
      template:
        src: src/zuccini
        dest: "/home/fruit/build/zuccini"
        backup: true
```

I want every task's template to have the `backup: true`, but it seems fairly repetitive to have to specify this for every single file. Is there a way to specify `backup: true` (or any other arbitrary setting) at the playbook level, so that I don't have to repeat this for every file I template out?

I've tried setting `backup: true` at various parent levels in the YAML, but ansible doesnt like it.

It seems tempting to try and use jinja loops to build a playbook with `backup: true` in every task, but Ansible's documentation says that we can't do that in a playbook

> ansible allows Jinja2 loops and conditionals in templates, but in playbooks, we do not use them. Ansible playbooks are pure machine-parseable YAML. This is a rather important feature as it means it is possible to code-generate pieces of files, or to have other ecosystem tools read Ansible files. Not everyone will need this but it can unlock possibilities.

-- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html

Comment: You can't use Jinja to build your playbook, but that doesn't mean you can't use a loop. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html